# R HIGHCHARTER - How to display additional series values on a highchart hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, highcharts, formatter

I want to display an additional data series on the hover of the highcharts I'm using on my flexdashboard. I understand that the way to do this is using the 'formatter' function of highcharts. I've been able to store the additional series in a random variable in my series data and call it using the formatter function, but I get the complete list for every bar in my highcharts plot. I need individual values for every point.

Here's the code:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Bottom Five Suppliers (Overall)") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = suppliers$Supplier[20:24], tickInterval = 1) %>%
    hc_yAxis(tickInterval = 1) %>% hc_add_series(data = suppliers$x[20:24],
            name = "Overall Supplier Score (Weighted)", resp = suppliers$respondents[20:24]) %>% 
hc_tooltip(valueDecimals = 2, useHTML = TRUE, formatter = JS("function()
{return this.series.options.resp;}")) 
%>% hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>% hc_plotOptions(
series = list(
  boderWidth = 0,
  dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
))
```

This is the result:
[image: image](http://imgur.com/a/rgcJm)[![Highchart for additional series]

As you can see, the data coming on hovering over the chart is different than the x or y axis. However, it is displaying the complete data for all the 5 bars rather than displaying one value for every bar.

I know I need to write a JavaScript function to match the values to rest of the data frame but I'm not sure how to do that (since I dont have much experience or knowledge of JS, sadly).

If I use a series being used on the x or y axis then it works fine, (using this.x or this.y) but using an additional series stored in a random variable does not work without this.series.options.seriesname and then also it returns the whole series.

**EDIT**

Here's the code to reproduce this example:

```
library (highcharter)
library (dplyr)
Suppliers= data.frame(Supplier = c('one','two','three','four','five'),
Value = c(1,2,3,4,5), respondents= c(5,1,4,12,5), 
Category = c('cat1','cat2','cat3','cat4','cat5'))

highchart() %>% 
hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
hc_title(text = "Bottom Five Suppliers (Overall)") %>% 
hc_xAxis(categories = Suppliers$Supplier, tickInterval = 1) %>%
hc_yAxis(tickInterval = 1) %>% hc_add_series(data = Suppliers$Value,
        name = "Overall Supplier Score (Weighted)", resp = Suppliers$respondents) %>% 
hc_tooltip(valueDecimals = 2, useHTML = TRUE, formatter = JS("function()
{return this.series.options.resp;}")) 
%>% hc_plotOptions(
series = list(
  boderWidth = 0,
  dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
))
```

When you hover over the produced highchart, it shows the complete respondents series instead of it showing individual values.

Comment: If you can generate a reproducible example will be easier to help you.

Comment: @jbkunst Thank you for responding! I have updated the question to include a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried something simple and it seemed to work. I just added the points of the x axis as index to the series I'm calling.

```
    library (highcharter)
    library (dplyr)
    Suppliers= data.frame(Supplier = c('one','two','three','four','five'),
    Value = c(1,2,3,4,5), respondents= c(5,1,4,12,5), 
    Category = c('cat1','cat2','cat3','cat4','cat5'))

     highchart() %>% 
     hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
     hc_title(text = "Bottom Five Suppliers (Overall)") %>% 
     hc_xAxis(categories = Suppliers$Supplier, tickInterval = 1) %>%
     hc_yAxis(tickInterval = 1) %>% hc_add_series(data = Suppliers$Value,
    name = "Overall Supplier Score (Weighted)", resp = Suppliers$respondents) %>% 
     hc_tooltip(valueDecimals = 2, useHTML = TRUE, formatter = JS("function()
      {return this.series.options.resp[this.point.x];}")) 
      %>% hc_plotOptions(
      series = list(
      boderWidth = 0,
      dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
    ))
```